# IIS port 80 In Use

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I cannot start my web site, as 80 is in use.

I've performed the checks, and it's being used by PID: 4 which turned out to be SYSTEM ( I obviously cannot stop this)

I have also stopped print spooler service, and made sure that I have stopped everything using the HTTP netstat, other than World Wide Web Publishing Service (needed for IIS)

It was working fine yesterday until I installed GIT, and restarted the VPS.

I have uninstalled GIT, restarted, and the problem still remains.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Check if anything in Reserved URLs uses port 80, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls

Answer (score 0):

While installing GIT you probably also installed Apache or other 3rth-party webserver. You could check if that's still on the server.

You don't need to stop all those services, and indeed SYSTEM is the user that uses IIS unless you tell it otherwise.

What do you get when you do following in CMD:

```
netstat -ab
```

You can check which executable is used on port 80.